# Problem with manipulating data object inside IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, vue.js, intersection, intersection-observer, vue-reactivity

I was trying to add a class to Header after some scrolling so I added an IntersectionObserver to Header component:

```
export default {
  
  data() {
    return {
      test: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      function(entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          console.log(entry)
          this.test = true
        })
      });
    observer.observe(this.$refs['header']);
  }
}
```

Somehow it is not working, because `test` variable won't change. `Console.log` executes properly every time, so I believe it is some reactivity problem? Maybe I created IntersectionObserver in a wrong place? I was messing a bit with `this.$nextTick()` and `this.$set`, but none of them helped. Cheers

Comment: can you try to wrap it on " this.$nextTick(() => { const observer ... })"

Comment: I did now, but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: instead of new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {}) do "new IntersectionObserver( (entries, observer) => {})"

Comment: This actually worked, ...but it fires only once, on page load. if I change `test` to number, and do `this.test++` inside `forEach` function it doesn't work more than once

Comment: You need to set the options which is your target and threshold please read the API here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API